# Issue while saving the state of application in angular while switching of tabs

Tags: angular

I am working on a application where the user can open multiple person data and each person details has multiple tabs like address, work etc. I want to save the state of each person so that the user can come back to the same state while switching between those two person.

For example if person 1 has work tab open and if I switch to person 2 perform some functionalities and come back to person 1 he should still see the work tab.

Is there any way to save the state of the complete component to the person so that I can display it again in angular 4.

Comment: Use state management techniques. Get started to ngrx-store using this [**repo**](https://github.com/aravindfz/ngrx-store-demo)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a service that holds the data until the user is ready to save it.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Here is a simple example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable() 
    export class DataService {
      serviceData: string; 
    }
```